# define type and functions which use this type as template parameters

Tags: c++

I'm making function to generate mip maps on CPU.
My goal is to write universal function which will work for many DXGI_FORMATs. Function is doing the same things for all DXGI_FORMAT combintaions, the only diffrence is data type and XMMATH functions to load and store it.

I try did it in nice way - by template parameters, like that:

```
#define AVERAGE(p, q) (((p - q) * 0.5f) + q)

template<typename XMATH_PIXEL_FORMAT,
         typename XMVECTOR(*XMATH_LOAD_FUNC)(const XMATH_PIXEL_FORMAT*),
         typename void(*XMATH_STORE_FUNC)(XMATH_PIXEL_FORMAT*, XMVECTOR)>
void minifyMipMap(XMATH_PIXEL_FORMAT* dst, const XMATH_PIXEL_FORMAT* src, size_t src_x, size_t src_y) {
  size_t x, y, x2, y2, dst_x = src_x >> 1, dst_y = src_y >> 1;
  XMVECTOR out, p00, p10, p01, p11; // p:xy

  for(y = 0; y < dst_y; ++y) { // for each dst line
    y2 = y << 1; // y2 = y * 2
    for(x = 0; x < dst_x; ++x) { // for each dst pixel
      x2 = x << 1; // x2 = x * 2

      // load 4 pixels
      p00 = XMATH_LOAD_FUNC(src + y2 * src_x + x2);
      p10 = XMATH_LOAD_FUNC(src + y2 * src_x + x2 + 1);
      p01 = XMATH_LOAD_FUNC(src + (y2 + 1) * src_x + x2);
      p11 = XMATH_LOAD_FUNC(src + (y2 + 1) * src_x + x2 + 1);

      // blend 4 pixels into 1
      out = AVERAGE(AVERAGE(p00, p10), AVERAGE(p01, p11));

      // store dest pixel
      XMATH_STORE_FUNC(dst + y * dst_x + x, out);
    }
  }
}


void test() {
  BYTE src[] = {
    0, 0, 0, 255, // black
    255, 255, 255, 255, // white
    0, 0, 0, 255, // black
    255, 255, 255, 255 // white
  };
  XMUBYTE4 dst[1]; // gray ???

  minifyMipMap<XMUBYTE4, XMLoadUByte4, XMStoreUByte4>(dst, (const XMUBYTE4*)src, 2, 2); // 2x2 = > 1x1
}
```

msvc says: C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'void minifyMipMap(XMATH_PIXEL_FORMAT *,const XMATH_PIXEL_FORMAT *,size_t,size_t)'
With the following template arguments:
'DirectX::PackedVector::XMUBYTE4'

I tried compile this code in few combinations, but without success (also i tried define type as class template and functions as static method parameters of this class, but it also fails).
I hope somehow it's possible in C++ to write it in nice way - without using #define's

Comment: I made horrible mistake, this doesn't works because void(*XMMATH_STORE_FUNC)(XMATH_PIXEL_FORMAT*, XMVECTOR) should be FXMVECTOR in 2nd parameter - not XMVECTOR - it's false alarm :> this template code works under msvc 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to accept arbitrary functions, don't do it this way. Accept a single template parameter per different function.

```
template<typename Func>
void foo(Func f) {
  // call f in any way you need
  f();
}

// can be used like this with functions
void bla() {}
f(&bla);
// Functors
struct X { void operator()() {} }
f(X());
```

The compiler will complain if a function is passed that cannot be called in the way your code calls it.

If you want to be really helpful to your users, you can provide some limited form of concept checking with `static_assert` and some meta-programming.

Comment: thank for answer, now days I often create functors classes like this